# mocha stuck, no output on console

Tags: mocha.js, yeoman

I'm using mocha within yeoman as a build target: `yeoman test`.

But the only output I see is

> Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
>
> Testing index.html

When I open that very same index.html in a browser, it works.

I'd expect the test results to show up in console.

Comment: Same problem here with `yeoman test`. The verbose flag does not help. I'm using requirejs to load modules to test and specs to test against. I have a modified version of the generated mocha runner and my config file loads the specs runner or my main application file, according to window.mocha is defined or not. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

My phantomjs was `1.4.1`, and it's not working just like you. After I update phantomjs to `1.8`, it's working.

I use MacOS, and the update commands are:

1. sudo brew update
2. sudo brew unlink phantomjs
3. sudo brew install phantomjs